# Working linux remote desktop setup

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, vncserver

I need some help to find a working linux remote desktop setup (Accessing my linux desktop from my windows laptop).
So far I have tryed:

> - **TigerVNCServer**
>
>   - Overall good, but this only lets me create a new desktop session instead of accessing the local display session (0).
> - **X11VNC**
>
>   - This lets me access the local display session, but has all sorts of problems with keyboard layout. I have debugged on/off on this for
>       about a month, and I got to solve problems with special characters,
>       numpad, shift. But I have reached an impass where there are different
>       keyboard problems with both -modtweak and -nomodtweak.
> - **Synergy**
>
>   - Solves my keyboard problems when I have a screen hooked up to the linux desktop, but not solving my remote desktop problem.

My physical setup - and the reason to why it needs to be like that - is a little complicated to explain, so please just accept the premise when you answer my question.

What I need is essentially a view to the remote session 0, which is working stable and with correct keyboard layout. I have a hard time understanding why tigervncserver can work so well with the keyboard layout, but none of the solutions which can do actual remote desktop, has so many problems with keyboard layout.
If you have any knowledge about a working setup, me (an my colleagues) would be glad to hear.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as it doesn't mention a specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I disagree. I try to solve the specific problem of not having a working remote desktop session to linux.
I list my requirements to such a session, and why all my previous attempts have resulted infailure.

Comment: @djsmiley2k From *"view to the remote session 0"*, it sounds like what OP wants is a way to do a shared remote desktop, not just open another X instance

Comment: @bertieb yup, I provided an answer on how to do that, what they didn't bother doing was explaining the rest of their problem(s).

Answer (score 1):

When you start your xvnc server, you can tell it which session to connect to:

`x0vncserver -display :0` (presuming your display is on the default of `0:0`

When you now connect, you'll be shown your existing desktop instead of a new session.

Comment: Just tryed it, and yes it does show display 0, but I am right back to the keyboard layout problems. 
I instantly concluded that AltGr doesn't work on x0vncserver.
And for some reason it seems like it doesn't support remote display of local cursor.